Downloading Static Files via Apache-deployed Angular app
I have an Angular 15 webapp, deployed on Apache/2.4.53, on a CentOS server.
I have used Rewrite rules to redirect all requests for my app to the index.html, so that Angular can handle the routing itself.
Now, because I have some PDFs that I want to download (yeah, they are distributed as assets with my Angular app), I want to exclude those files/directories from the rewriting.
This is the latest Apache config I tried:
<Directory /var/www/html/mysubdomain/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted

  RewriteEngine On

  # Prevent recursion for existing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|pdf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|js|css)$ - [L]

  # Fallback for everything else to index.html
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
</Directory>

From what I've searched (google & chatgpt) this should work properly, but when I try to download one of my files, I get a PDF that has the index.html as its content.
I also tried using the "FallbackResource /index.html" directive.
When using this, every time I tried to download a PDF I got back an HTTP 500 and Apache logged:
Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

I don't really think it plays a role in it, but also here is the code I use to download my files:
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = environment.baseHref + filepath;
link.download = filename + '.pdf';
link.click();

I am not at all particular about the way I am going to handle this.
I have full access to the server, Apache, and Angular app.
Any and all suggestions are welcome, thank you in advance!

I assume that you are putting all your assets in one folder, which is a common structure.
This should make it easier to manage the access to your exposed assets files.
Then you could just redirect every request to your index.html except for the assets folder by using RewriteRule and RewriteCond together:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f // make sure that the request is not file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/.+|/dir2/.+ // and not your assets folders
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L] // redirect if the above conditions match


Yes, precisely. I'm putting them all in the same 'assets' folder and in sub-folders therein. I will try it out in a bit, thank you! Am I understanding correctly that the "/dir2/" part refers to any other folders I might want to exclude from redirection?

Yes/dir2/ is any other folder that contains assets if you have one. But probably in your case you have only one, so you can just use /assets/.+ and remove the rest.
